# Software to know the messages and calls list of an android mobile phone from a PC

Tags: android

I need a software that tells me the messages and calls list of an android mobile phone in which the software is installed. I will tell the specifications -

1. It should be a free software.
2. It must use less battery.
3. It should be able to tell me the details of the messages and calls list by e-mailing or by some other means when ever possible.
4. The mobile phone user shouldn't be alerted about its usage(it should work like a spy software).

Is there such an android app ?

Comment: Maybe you could explain a little background (aka "user story") for what its needed? Currently it sounds like you want to install it on someone else's device without consent – which makes people not that willing to jump in.